# How to make Entity Framework use 1 update query instead of 1 for each record?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have this code:

```
var query = _calendarDayRepo.Queryable().Where(x => x.Date >= calendarDayDto.Date);

foreach (var calendarDay in query)
{
    calendarDay.WorkingDayCounter += (updatedEntityAdd ? 1 : -1);
}

await _calendarDayRepo.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I'm using a SQL Server database.

For now, EF will do a query to update each record, but I believe it would be more performant if EF would generate only 1 query, to update all the records at once.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You may want to look at [EntityFramework.Extended for batch update & delete](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/55d96a/entity-framework-batch-insert-update-delete-operations/)

Comment: See [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) - look for the term "update"

Comment: I'd recommend a much more powerful ORM: linq2db. See how easy to do an [update](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db#update) in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using entity framework there are two ways to fetch data. Only one of them is used to fetch items that need to be updated.

If you query data using `Select`, then the query is executed using a SQL `Select ... From ...` etc. The fetched data is returned to you. The DbContext won't save this data. This method is the preferred method if you don't plan to update the fetched data, because it is the most efficient one for this usage

If you want to update items using entity framework, the proper method is to fetch the data to be updated, update the properties that need to be changed and call `SaveChanges`. This latter will do the actual updating.

To use this method, you need to query the compete objects, without using Select. The DbContext has a ChangeTracker. If you execute such a query, the fetched object is put into the ChangeTracker, as well as a copy of it. You get the reference to the copy (or maybe the original, which one doesn't matter). Because you have the reference, changing properties will change the copy in the ChangeTracker. When you call SaveChanges, all originals in the ChangeTracker are compared by value with their copies. The changes are translated into a SQL `Update ... Set ... Where ...` statement.

By now, it should be clear to you to see that it is not efficient to fetch items that you don't plan to update without using Select.

> When using entity framework always use `Select` to fetch items, and select only the properties that you actually plan to use. Only fetch without Select, only use `Include` if you plan to update the fetched items.

### Examples

Suppose you have a database with Customers, Products, Orders, etc. A one-to-many between Customers and Orders, and a one-to-many between Products and Orders.

"Give me the address and some other information of all Orders that are not paid yet, because I want to send them a reminder"

No update, use a Select. Only fetch the items that you actually plan to use.

```
DateTime dueDate = DateTime.Today - TimeSpan.FromDays(14); // 2 weeks ago
using (var dbContext = new OrderContext(...))
{
    var ordersThatNeedAReminder = dbContext.Orders
        .Where(order => !order.Paid && order.DueDate <= dueDate)
        .Select(order => new
        {
             Customer = new
             {
                 // only select the Customer Properties that you plan to use
                 Name = order.Customer.Name,
                 AddressLine1 = order.Customer.Address.AddressLine1,
                 ...

                 // probably not needed:
                 // Id = customer.Id
             },

             Order = new
             {
                 DeliveryDate = order.DeliveryDate,
                 PayDate = order.PayDate,
                 Amount = order.Total,
                 ...
             },
       })
       .ToList();

       ProcessNonPaidOrders(ordersThatNeedAReminder);
}
```

Because I used `Select` to fetch all items, the fetched items are not put in the ChangeTracker.

"All lawn mowers need a price adjustment"

```
using (var dbContext = new OrderContext(...))
{
    // Fetch the lawnMowers
    IEnumerable<Product> lawnMowers = dbContext.Products
        .Where(product => product.Type == ProductType.LawnMower)
        .ToList();

    UpdatePrice(lawnMowers, ...);    // not part of the question

    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Because the data is queried without Select, the fetched item and a copy are put in the ChangeTracker. You get a reference to the copy, of which property Price is changed. `SaveChanges` will compare the Original and the Copy of all items in the ChangeTracker, and will create the proper SQL update for all changed properties.

This method is the preferred method to perform updates.

- Advantage: you get the latest version of the item just before you change it.
- Disadvantage: you have to fetch the complete item (not the items that are referenced via a foreign key, unless they also need an update).

There is a method where you can immediately put the value of a changed item in the ChangeTracker.

Update the price of the Husqvarna lawn Mower

```
long husqvarnaLawnMowerId = ...
Product lawnMowerHusqvarna = FetchProduct(husqvaranLawnMowerId);
decimal adjustedPrice = AskOperatorForNewPrice(lawnMowerHusqvarna);

lawnMowerHusqvarna.Price = adjustedPrice;

using (var dbContext = new OrderContext(...))
{
    dbContext.Products.Attach(lawnMowerHusqvarna);
    dbContext.Savechanges();
}
```

So if you already know the value of all the fields of the object to update, you don't have to fetch them first.

Be aware though, that others might have changed one or more properties. You will lose the changes made by yourself or others since you fetched the current value.

Therefore I wouldn't recommend this method. Usually the number of changes to the database are relatively small compared to the number of queries. Quite often the changes are after operator input, hence these changes won't have to be super fast. My advice would be: don't use this method.